# backbone handle index page with a layout

Tags: layout, backbone.js, model-view-controller

I am new to backbone. Have everything working except when I click back to the first page. I can't figure out how to make it load properly. This is in a .net mvc app so the index page loads the layout page. If I put a call to the Index page in the home function, then the browser gets in an infinite loop, loading the layout page which contains the code below which reloads the index again.

```
        <script>
        var MainRouter = Backbone.Router.extend ({
            routes: {
                '': 'home',
                'Home': 'HHome',
                'About': 'AAbout',
                'Contact': 'CContact'
            },
            home: function () {
                //WHAT TO DO HERE?

            },
            HHome: function () {
                ajaxCall('/Home/Home');
            },
            AAbout: function () {
                ajaxCall('/Home/about');
            },
            CContact: function () {
                ajaxCall('/Home/Contact');
            }
        });

        //define our new instance of router
        var appRouter = new MainRouter();

        Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });


        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('a').click(function(event) {

                event.preventDefault();

                var url = $(this).attr('href');

                appRouter.navigate(url, { trigger: true });
            });
        });
```

Any suggestions would be great. 
Thanx ahead of time.

Comment: what do you mean 'the index page loads the layout page?'

Comment: In .net MVC you have a layout page where you put your standard stuff that will be on every page. IE the logo/navbar/footer. Depending on how you build the site, either only the index will load the layout(in a spa) or every page will. I don't think there is a way to load the layout without using a regular cshtml page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to your `ajaxCall` returning the MVC view, you just need to disable the layout for those views by placing the following at the top of the views:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Comment: The how would I get the layout on the page in the first place?

Comment: Layout will be added by default. This overrides that so the Layout is not rendered for that specific view.

Comment: Something has to tell MVC to call the layout page. If every view has Layout=null, the layout never gets called. Not saying there isn't a way around that, but I haven't been able to find 1.

Comment: You don't use it for *every* view, just use it for the views that are called from Backbone. You still need a Index/Main/Initial page that inherits the layout, which then runs the JS you posted in your question.

Comment: And that is what I am trying to figure out how to do. When it first loads, the default path is empty and loads the index page with the layout, but when I navigate away via backbone and click the back button, that route is empty and doesn't load anything. If I put a non index layout in there, then that will load first without the layout, if I put one with the layout, it goes into an infinite loop.